# Any way to check which AWS Service Endpoints Cloudfront is pulling static files from

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Have a Django Website and I am using CDN / Cloudfront for all the static and media files. My origin S3 that I am using is `us-east-1`. When I have turned on the cloundfront all is nicely working. Is there a way to check somehow if I load the static or media file over CDN URL or somehow in the AWS console or somewhere (I can be logged into AWS) - from which AWS Service Endpoints Cloudfront is pulling static files from? Let's say if I would be in Japan - that I can see it is pulling from there `Asia Pacific (Tokyo) / ap-northeast-1` for example, depends where I am located. It is just for check purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I found this documentation: [Locations and IP Address Ranges of CloudFront Edge Servers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LocationsOfEdgeServers.html)

It looks like, you may check IP from where you load an asset, and then by IP find a region in [ip-ranges.json](https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json)

Comment: Ok, I have checked the ip of 1 of the asset and check against both lists, JSON and Cloudfront Edge servers and none found - I know there are not last digits in the list but I have tried 1st numbers XX.XXX and it found it but not XX.XXX.XXX - this was not found at all in both so not sure. Try for example this: http://d7uri8nf7uskq.cloudfront.net/tools/list-cloudfront-ips and IP is 54.230.30.10 - it is not even in both lists not even 54.230.30

Comment: 54.230.30.10 is covered in subnet "54.230.0.0/16".